# Are Bazaar tags versioned? How Can I get the log of tag changes?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

Are Bazaar tags versioned/controlled within the repository?

I found this article[1] from 2005 (bzr 0.15) that says tags are versioned, but I cant seem to find any other supporting documentation about how to get revision history on tags. i.e. If I change the tag RELEASE_1 from revision 12 to revision 15, I want to see who did it, when, and why. Is this possible?

I've tried the command:

```
bzr log -r tag:tag_name
```

But this only give me the revision history of the revision associated with the tag.

1: http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Specs/Tagging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately tags are not versioned in bzr.

The article you referred to spec on how it would be implemented, but in reality it was implemented differently.

According to [bzr help tag](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/tag-help.html), Tags are stored in the branch, and are copied from one branch to another along when you branch, push, pull or merge.

There is a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/609197) for tags to be versioned.